# AzureStack POC Machine can't connet to the internet after running deployment script

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines

I have deployed Windows Azure Stack TP3 in our server. The deployment status completed successfully and I can log in to the Azure portal from MAS-CON01 VM.

[image]

The VM needs to connect to the internet to download an image. I can ping the Public IP address but I can't resolve domains. I added a dns record entry but the problem still persists.

[image]

Comment: Could you ping google?

Comment: no, I can't ping google domain.

Comment: I got an update from MSDN forum. The problem because DNS issue. https://goo.gl/S7YiLr

Answer (score 0):

There are DNS issue and network configuration did not succeed successfully. The resolution is redeploy with define network configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen, if your network from which you are getting the internet is DHCP enabled with 192.168.0.0 network, which will create conflicts with the virtual networks of the Azure Stack.